# ERROR: The checksum of android-studio-ide doesn't match. Corrupted download? Aborting

Tags: java, application-development, android, android-studio, ubuntu-make

More than three times:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat android
Script started on 2017-10-26 05:49:38-0700
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ umake -v android android-studio --accept-license
INFO: Logging level set to INFO
INFO: Create a new apt cache
INFO: clang isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: Don't register Eclipse ADT as it's not installable on this configuration.
INFO: Don't register Dart Editor as it's not installable on this configuration.
INFO: libxtst6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxext6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxi6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxt6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxpm4:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxmu6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libgtk2.0-0:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libatk1.0-0:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libcairo2:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libexpat1:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libfontconfig1:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libfreetype6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libglib2.0-0:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libice6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libpango1.0-0:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libpng12-0:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libsm6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxau6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxcursor1:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxdmcp6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxfixes3:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libx11-6:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxinerama1:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxrandr2:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libxrender1:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libnss3-1d:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libnspr4-0d:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libcurl3:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libasound2:i386 isn't installed
INFO: libpng12-0:i386 isn't available on this platform
INFO: libnss3-1d:i386 isn't available on this platform
INFO: libnspr4-0d:i386 isn't available on this platform
INFO: Don't register Stencyl as it's not installable on this configuration.
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jdk isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jre isn't installed
INFO: openjdk-7-jre isn't installed
INFO: clang isn't installed
INFO: libicu-dev isn't installed
Choose installation path: /home/thufir/.local/share/umake/android/android-studio
INFO: Start downloading DownloadItem(url='https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html', checksum=None, headers=None, ignore_encoding=False, cookies=None) in memory
INFO: https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html download finished
INFO: All pending downloads for [DownloadItem(url='https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html', checksum=None, headers=None, ignore_encoding=False, cookies=None)] done
INFO: Installation ['libncurses5:i386', 'libstdc++6:i386', 'zlib1g:i386', 'openjdk-8-jdk'] pending
INFO: Start downloading DownloadItem(url='https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux.zip', checksum=Checksum(checksum_type=<ChecksumType.sha1: 'sha1'>, checksum_value='7991f95ea1b6c55645a3fc48f1534d4135501a07b9d92dd83672f936d9a9d7a2'), headers=None, ignore_encoding=False, cookies=None) to a temp file
Downloading and installing requirements
ERROR: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux.zip couldn't finish download: The checksum of https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux.zip doesn't match. Corrupted download? Aborting.
INFO: All pending downloads for [DownloadItem(url='https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux.zip', checksum=Checksum(checksum_type=<ChecksumType.sha1: 'sha1'>, checksum_value='7991f95ea1b6c55645a3fc48f1534d4135501a07b9d92dd83672f936d9a9d7a2'), headers=None, ignore_encoding=False, cookies=None)] done
100% |#####################################################################################|
ERROR: The checksum of https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/3.0.0.18/android-studio-ide-171.4408382-linux.zip doesn't match. Corrupted download? Aborting.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ exit
exit

Script done on 2017-10-26 06:18:19-0700
thufir@dur:~$
```

Googling the checksum from the console gives this link:

> Linux     android-studio-ide-162.4069837-linux.zip    468 MB (490,782,431
>   bytes)
>     1383cfd47441e5f820b6257a1bdd683e0e980bc76c7f2027ef84dc2e6ad2f17f

https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

which looks like it matches to me.  So the error doesn't even make sense.

System info:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ umake --version
16.11.1
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=17.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=artful
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 17.10"
thufir@dur:~$
```

Comment: umake is buggy sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I have run into the same error attempting to install arduino IDE on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
umake ide arduino
```

Which failed with:

```
ERROR: The checksum of https://www.arduino.cc/download_handler.php doesn't match. Corrupted download? Aborting.
```

In my case the solution was to use the latest version of ubuntu-make from the PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lyzardking/ubuntu-make
sudo apt update
```

Get rid of all the old stuff:

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-make
sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean
rm -rf ~/.local/share/umake
```

And reinstall `umake`:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-make
```

Then retry your umake install and you should be good to go.