# PPA does not have a release date: apt update failed for some reason

Tags: command-line, apt, application-development, ppa, repository

Trying to [remove](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/45156) a ppa which I shouldn't have [installed](https://askubuntu.com/q/148932/45156):

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 05:57 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 26 05:52 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  166 Oct 26 05:57 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 Oct 26 05:57 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  156 Oct 26 05:57 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 05:57 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 05:57 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful main
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio
Updating packages lists
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
Warning:  apt-get update failed for some reason
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [70.3 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-fonville/android-studio/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease                     
Get:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [76.7 kB]               
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful InRelease          
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful InRelease  
Hit:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                       
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful Release            
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
thufir@dur:~$
```

Because it's out of [date](https://askubuntu.com/a/634084/45156) (apparently).  How do I safely remove this ppa?  By which I mean using `ppa-purge` as that seems the best tool.  (In the [context](https://askubuntu.com/q/969080/45156) of installing android studio.)

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "safely", but you can just remove the files that list this ppa, or comment the ppa out in those files and you would have done it.

Comment: @Ziazis yeah, would've preferred to use the purge utility.  thanks tho.

Comment: So what happens with `ppa-purge`? Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: I assume you want to use the ppa-purge because you installed something and want it to be removed? Because if nothing was installed it makes no sense to use that.

Comment: @DKBose no, it comes back with:  `E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/paolorotolo/android-studio/ubuntu artful Release' does not have a Release file.
` and that's it.

Comment: @Ziazis ok, thanks, I'll just comment out then :)

Answer (score 0):

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paolorotolo/android-studio  --remove
 Automatic builds for Android Studio by Google packaged for Ubuntu.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~paolorotolo/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:maarten-fonville/android-studio --remove
 Automatically generated builds of the latest Android Studio
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~maarten-fonville/+archive/ubuntu/android-studio
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel removing it.

thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease [70.3 kB]
Get:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease [76.7 kB]               
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu artful InRelease                    
Hit:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease                       
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,184 B]
Get:7 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 Packages [9,000 B]
Get:8 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main i386 Packages [9,012 B]
Get:9 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [8,268 B]
Get:10 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe i386 Packages [4,112 B]
Get:11 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe amd64 Packages [4,116 B]
Get:12 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,188 B]
Fetched 186 kB in 1s (179 kB/s)                                      
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
11 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
thufir@dur:~$
```

and then:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Oct 26 08:46 paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm maarten-fonville-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ sudo rm paolorotolo-ubuntu-android-studio-artful.list.save 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ 
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$ ll
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:51 ./
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 26 08:44 ../
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  136 Oct 26 08:46 webupd8team-ubuntu-java-artful.list.save
thufir@dur:/etc/apt/sources.list.d$
```

curious as to why `ppa-purge` wouldn't remove those `ppa`'s, though.